# Add to polynomials

Tags: python

In this code there are four test cases. Three test cases are camed successfully but 4th test case was not getting expected output. Please help me.

I got 0x^3 as output in 4th test case but expected output is 0

Add two polynomials

Given two polynomials A and B, write a program that adds the given two polynomials A and B

Output

Print the addition of polynomials A and B.

If the degree of polynomial is zero and the constant term is also zero, then just print 0 to represent the polynomial.

For term Cix^Pi, if the coefficient of the term Ci is 1, simply print x^Pi instead of 1x^Pi.Explanation

We need all test cases can be came when code was run. I want exact outputs for all test cases

Here is the question and test case inputs and outputs in the below url link

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DhE2akiG_pX_Q_EoKaEY9EapSgz3xWhY/view?usp=sharing

```
def check_polinom(polinom):
            checked = []
            while polinom:
                    tmp = polinom.pop(0)
                    if polinom:
                            for i in range(len(polinom)-1, -1, -1):
                                    if polinom[i][0] == tmp[0]:
                                            tmp[1] += polinom[i][1]
                                            polinom.pop(i)
                    checked.append(tmp)
            return checked
    
    
    def add_polinoms(pol_1, pol_2):
            added = []
            while pol_1 or pol_2:
                    if pol_1:
                            tmp = pol_1.pop(0)
                            for i in range(len(pol_2)):
                                    if pol_2[i][0] == tmp[0]:
                                            tmp[1] += pol_2[i][1]
                                            pol_2.pop(i)
                                            break
                    else:
                            tmp = pol_2.pop(0)
    
    
                    added.append(tmp)
            added.sort(reverse=True)
            return(added)
    
    
    def print_polinom(polinom):
            s = ''
            if polinom:
                    if polinom[0][1] < 0:
                            s += '-'
                            polinom[0][1] = -polinom[0][1]
                    if polinom[0][1] == 1:
                            if polinom[0][0] == 0:
                                    s += str(polinom[0][1])
                            elif polinom[0][0] == 1:
                                    s += 'x'
                            else:
                                    s += 'x^' + str(polinom[0][0])
                    else:
                            if polinom[0][0] == 1:
                                    s += str(polinom[0][1]) + 'x'
                            elif polinom[0][0] == 0:
                                    s += str(polinom[0][1])
                            else:
                                    s += str(polinom[0][1]) + 'x^' + str(polinom[0][0])                        
                    polinom.pop(0)
            for el in polinom:
                    if el[1] == 0:
                            continue
                    elif el[1] < 0:
                            s += ' - '
                            el[1] = -el[1]
                            
                    else:
                            s += ' + '
                    if el[1] == 1:
                            if el[0] == 0:
                                    s += str(el[1])
                            elif el[0] == 1:
                                    s += 'x'
                            else:
                                    s += 'x^' + str(el[0])
                    else:
                            if el[0] == 1:
                                    s += str(el[1]) + 'x'
                            elif el[0] == 0:
                                    s += str(el[1])
                            else:
                                    s += str(el[1]) + 'x^' + str(el[0])
            print(s)
    
    
    def input_data():
            while True:
                    try:
                            n = int(input())
                            break
                    except:
                            print('enter an integer N')
                            continue
            a = list()
            i = 1
            while n > i-1:
                    try:
                            tmp = list(map(int,(input()).split()))
                            if len(tmp) != 2:
                                    print('enter two space separated integers')
                                    continue
                            a.append(tmp)
                            i += 1
                    except:
                            print('enter two space separated integers')
    
    
            return a
    
    
    
    
    a = check_polinom(input_data())
    b = check_polinom(input_data())
    c = add_polinoms(a,b)
    print_polinom(c)
```

Comment: Hello, what is the result you get for the last testcase?

Comment: Sir I got 0x^3 as output in 4th test case but expected output is 0

Comment: Anybody Please help me

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you code does not clean up 0 coefficients. An additional phase should be added to your processing. Once you have the final coefficients of your polinomial, you should have two adjustments. You have already described one, that turns items with coefficient 1 from the form 1*x to simply x. Another one is when you turn 0*x to nothing. Then you only have to be careful to output something, so you should not turn every term into nothing. That is why there is a description to represent it as 0.

The easiset way to make this work would thus be:

1. Add a function to check if a polinomial has all zero coefficients: is_zero_polinom
2. Do something like this in print_polinom:

> ```
> if is_zero_polinom(polinom):
>    print('0')
>    return
> <here comes the current code>
> ```

Comment: Sir Where i can put this code in my code sir. Sir if you don't mine please put this function in code and publish entire code to me sir